# How to publish symbolic matrices in latex format in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, latex, octave, publish, symbolic-math

I have a project in which I have to publish symbolic matrices in latex format.
An example of a matrix is the following:

```
J1 =
[            1,            0,              a]
[            1,            0,             -a]
[ cos(beta_3s), sin(beta_3s), b*sin(beta_3s)]
```

If I try to publish it in latex format, I get the same equation as above:

```
\begin{document}
        \color{lightgray} \begin{verbatim} 
J1 =

[            1,            0,              a]
[            1,            0,             -a]
[ cos(beta_3s), sin(beta_3s), b*sin(beta_3s)]
\end{verbatim} \color{black}
```

As you can see, the matrix is not published in the neat way that latex can actually write the matrix.
Moreover, if I tried solving the problem using a function that I created as follows:

```
function lat = tex(input)
    lat=['$',latex(input),'$'];
end
```

This outputs the desired code which is:

```
'$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} -\sin\left(\beta _{\mathrm{1s}}\right) & \cos\left(\beta _{\mathrm{1s}}\right) & b\,\sin\left(\beta _{\mathrm{1s}}\right)\\ \sin\left(\beta _{\mathrm{2s}}\right) & -\cos\left(\beta _{\mathrm{2s}}\right) & b\,\sin\left(\beta _{\mathrm{2s}}\right)\\ -\sin\left(\beta _{\mathrm{3c}}\right) & \cos\left(\beta _{\mathrm{3c}}\right) & c\,\sin\left(\beta _{\mathrm{3c}}\right) \end{array}\right)$'
```

However, if I try to publish the script in latex format using the function above and the disp function, `(disp(tex(J1)))`, I get the following output in the published .tex file:

```
\begin{document}
        \color{lightgray} \begin{verbatim}$\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 0 & a\\ 1 & 0 & -a\\ \cos\left(\beta _{\mathrm{3s}}\right) & \sin\left(\beta _{\mathrm{3s}}\right) & b\,\sin\left(\beta _{\mathrm{3s}}\right) \end{array}\right)$
\end{verbatim} \color{black}
```

So as you can see, the code is now published with `\begin{verbatim} \end{verbatim}` . So, instead of showing the matrix, the latex code will show the code instead.
Is there a way to output the latex code in a way that it will be outside `\begin{verbatim} \end{verbatim}` and make it display the symbolic matrix?

In addition, please note that the main issue is that the user of the final code will be able to choose a .txt table. Then, from that table, all the computations will be done and published to a .tex file . So, everything should be done automatically and each time, the table may change. An example of such a table is as follows:

[image: Example of a table that the user will input]

I am sorry for the long question but I saw some people tried to ask the same question but did not find an answer. So, I tried to detail my problem as much as possible.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am missing something here. Where are you trying to write this? MATLAB will not accept latex comments like \begin{document}. Where is the link between MATLAB and latex? Are you using some particular MATLAB functionality that creates latex docs?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but presumably if you're trying to convert a matrix into a latex table, this function will come in handy: https://octave.sourceforge.io/miscellaneous/function/textable.html